# Java: Jersey rest service URL mapping problem

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I´m trying to configure jersey rest services for my java web application. The problem I´m facing is that I can get required response only on root services URL. Any other URL I have tried to set is returning HTTP 404 Not Found.

Following configuration is working:

```
package cz.mono.wb.rest
@Path("/")
public class UserService 
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String respondAsReady() {
        return "Web service is ready!";
    }
}
```

When I access URL server:port/contextRoot/rest/ in browse, its returning correct response, but when i try to set the @Path annotation for example like this:

```
package cz.mono.wb.rest
@Path("/user")
public class UserService 
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String respondAsReady() {
        return "Web service is ready!";
    }
}
```

and try to access URL

```
server:port/contextRoot/rest/user/
```

or

```
server:port/contextRoot/rest/user
```

its returning 404.

Jersey configuration looks like this:
web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>cz.mono.wb.rest</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Cannot see your imports. Is the @Path annotation from the right place?

Comment: Jsut tried with your configuration and works well on Tomcat 8.0.
What server are you using? Any startup Log?

Comment: Anyway here the project I used so you can compare:
https://github.com/Macs75/xxx

Comment: Import for path annotation - javax.ws.rs.Path. @Massimo: good point, thanks. I'm running on wildlfy 15. I've uploaded startup log here: http://www.fltk.cz/data/wildfly_log.txt . There are some exceptions, I tought it was about EJB support, which I'm not using, but there probably is some problem. I need to do deeper investigation.

Answer (score 1):

As you already specified `url-pattern` in your config as:

`<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>`

Now you dont need to have `/` before your path in resource. Just try `@Path("user")` and it should work now.

Comment: You are probably right, I was also trying that, but its still not working (host/contextRoot/jerseyRoot/user)

Answer (score 1):

Just looked at you code and in an exception it say it has disabled JAR-RS:

```
 (EJBComponentProviderFactoryInitilizer.java:89) - The EJB interceptor binding API is not available. JAX-RS EJB support is disabled.
```

Mosto problably solving this problem will solve your issue.
Hope I was helpful to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The path `/user` is absolute (notice the forward slash `/` prefixed before `user`) which means it points to the root of the hostname. Thus, it effectively points to `<hostname>/user` and not to `<hostname>/root/user`. So, to fix this just change the value of @Path annotation to `"/root/user"`.

Comment: The slash at the beginning of the @Path annotation above the class points to the host:port/contextRoot/jerseyRoot/ (in my case http://localhost:8080/wb/rest/) . If I set UserService class annotation @Path("/"), I´m getting correct response on mentioned URL. Any way, I tried to set the @Path("/rest/user") and access it on localhost/wb/rest/user and its not working (jersey returns 404).